# Python Virtualenv not working since upgrading to OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: django, virtualenv

I just updated my OS X from 10.7 to 10.8 (moutain lion).
When I try to run virtualenv venv --distribute
I get this error

```
File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
working_set.require(__requires__)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: virtualenv==1.8.2
```

When I run which python I get /usr/bin/python
When I run which virtualenv I get /usr/local/bin/virtualenv

It seems like the path has changed with the upgrade and does someone knows how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Check to see if `.../Extras/lib/python` contains virtualenv. Alternatively, see if you can find `virtualenv` on your system anywhere, and ensure that it exists from within the path that python can find.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by uninstalling virtualenv and then reinstalling virtualenv.

Uninstall

```
sudo pip uninstall virtualenv
```

Install

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```